# SQL pagination without offset and index column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hbase

My database has millions of records and that is being used on a portal to display to the user and pagination is done using offset and also the data is sorted by some column, Is there any alternate solution to offset and using any index column such as auto increment field or unique field, it does not works if I have to sort with some different column, also even when the row is deleted it does not return expected results.

I am running sql queries in my java application, I've tried a way by only adding limit to my queries. So it works like the offset will always be zero and the limit will be number of (limit + offset) as per pagination logic

Ex : User requests for 10 records per page and navigates to 51 page

Alternate Logic : limit 10 offset 500 -> limit = 510

Queries look like

```
select * from history limit 510 order by log_date;
```

so with the help of `absolute` method of `ResultSet` I navigate to the row number as per the specified offset and fetch the results after that row

```
    -- No of rows returned 510

    rs.absolute(500);
while(rs.next()){
//store data in the object
}
```

but even by this way I m telling data base to return 510 records and if user navigates to the last page it will fetch all the rows which will be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is only applicable to phoenix 4.7 (hdp 2.5) and the way I found was to sort the data in ascending order with the primary key and if there is the composite key data was sorted as per the first column of the key and then the offset and limit works properly.

Answer (score 0):

So you are hitting the DB on every new page request - with this out of the confusion :

In the sample you gave, you are fetching all of the result set into java application and then filtering. Let the Database do the filtering and give you the result. Send the PAGE_NUMBER you want into the db query itself.

```
select * from history limit 510 order by log_date 
OFFSET PAGE_NUMBER*MAX_ROWS_TO_SELECT  ROWS FETCH NEXT MAX_ROWS_TO_SELCET ROWS ONLY;
```

As mentioned in the above sample, you have to get only 10 records. This is the efficient way for you to get the required page content in optimized DB resultset size.

Comment: But still i m using `offset` clause to fetch the results

Comment: To filter the record in java code was a type of alternate approach for using `offset` clause to fetch the results.